# The style on this button isn't displaying on mobile (iOS)

Tags: ios, html, css

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hV0r.jpg) on mobile Safari & Chrome (iPhone 5c, iOS8).

[This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9C0w.jpg) what it should look like.

The :hover state is working after I tap the button.

Here is my code. Works fine on Chrome on Android 5.1 though. Strange (to me).

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

}
#feedback-page {
  text-align: center;
}
#form-main {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#form-div {
  background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.4);
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: -260px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}
.feedback-input {
  color: #3c3c3c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.feedback-input:focus {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: 3px solid #db1d1d;
  color: #3c3c3c;
  outline: none;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
}
.focused {
  color: #db1d1d;
  border: #db1d1d solid 3px;
}
/* Icons ---------------------------------- */

#name {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#name:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 8px 5px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#email {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#email:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#comment {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150%;
  resize: vertical;
}
input:hover,
textarea:hover,
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: white;
}
#button-red {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #db1d1d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#button-red:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #db1d1d;
}
.submit:hover {
  color: #db1d1d;
}
.ease {
  width: 0px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
.submit:hover .ease {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  #form-div {
    left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="form-main">
  <div id="form-div">
    <form action="//formspree.io/emailemailemail@gmail.com" method="POST" class="form" id="form1">

      <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
      </p>
      <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />
      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
      </p>

      <p class="text">
        <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
      </p>


      <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-red" />
        <div class="ease"></div>

      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="{{store_url}}/page/thanks" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: So the issue is that the button has rounded corners? Is the color also wrong? Is this all of your CSS?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I didn't make that clear. :/ The color is more of a gradient instead of the fill it's supposed to be. This is the full code for the html and css for the button.

Comment: Well there's nothing in your code that would be styling it like that. Is this page on a site that would have CSS you don't control? Or is it possible that you have CSS being loaded on this page (even CSS you wrote) that might be affecting this button? Look for something within a media query. If you have an iPhone and a charging cable, you can use safari to inspect your page on mobile.

Comment: Yes is it within a tictail page but all the code for the form is unique to me, as in I added it and there are no conflicting class names or id's. It works on Chrome on Android though which is what really confuses me.

Comment: My best guess is that there's code somewhere that's inside a very small media query, so it's only affecting your iPhone 5c (which is almost certainly smaller than a device with android on it). The code is probably somewhat general - affecting all `inputs` or something like that.

Comment: I just went through every border-radius and not a single one made a difference when commented out then refreshed. :( I thought you were on to something there. You're right about the screen sizes though, the android has a bigger screen and would fall under different queries.

Comment: Huh, lame. Well I would then definitely try to inspect your code on your iPhone and see if you can see where the styles are coming from.

Comment: Regaddi was able to help me. It was the default iOS styling of the submit button overriding my styles. It was the same on an iPhone 4 and iPad 2. Looks perfect now. Thanks for helping me out though. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following to your #button-red styles:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
```

This should override any iOS specific browser styles for the button.
There may be some existing CSS definitions in included CSS files, so for debugging purposes you might try to use the `!important` statement.

Comment: Refined my solution, maybe you get more success using -webkit-appearance and/or -webkit-border-radius

Comment: Thanks for your efforts man but they just don't seem to work. I don't get it. In it's default state it looks like the crappy rounded button but if I tap it then it switches to the more modern flat design I had intended.

Comment: The -webkit-appearance: none; worked. I must of mistyped it last night. Thank you very much for your help. Lesson learned: don't trust iOS styling!!